# Text character limit

Tags: javascript

I have this script and want to implement 12 character limit for each name like first name, last name and middle name can not have more than 12 characters each.

```js
var name = prompt("Please enter (Last name, First name, Middle initial)");

function fullName(alf) {
    var validate = alf.match(/^[a-zA-Z', ]+$/);
    if (validate == name)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}


var tst = fullName(name);
if (tst)
    document.write("Valid Name");
else
    document.write("Invalid Name");
```

Comment: `alf.match(/^[a-zA-Z', ]{,12}$/);`

Comment: Just tell me the how the names will be entered. I mean separated by commas, or by spaces. e.g Armstrong, M, James or Armstrong M James

Comment: If you just need to validate the names are not greater than 12 characters, why not simply check the length of the input and have an if condition to check if it is greater than 12?

Comment: Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Where are you stuck here? Do you not know how split the data into the three names? Do you not know how to obtain the length of a string? Do you not know how to check it once you have it? Do you want to incorporate the check into the regular expression, and don't know how to do that? Of course, you shouldn't be checking names at all. See link in previous comment.

Comment: @ArunPJohny He wants to check the length of each name, not the length of the entire input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fairly simple. Just check the prompt input length as in this snippet. (However  if you use input field instead of a prompt you can limit its length by defining "maxlength" e.g. `<input type="text" name="yourname" maxlength="10">`)

```js
var name = prompt("Please enter (Last name, First name, Middle initial)");

function fullName(alf) {
    var validate = alf.match(/^[a-zA-Z', ]+$/);
    if (validate == name)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}

var len = name.length;
var tst = fullName(name);

if (tst && len <= 39)              // len 12 * 3 for each value + 3 for spaces/commas separating names.

    document.write("Valid Name");
else
    document.write("Invalid Name");
```

Comment: `if (validate == name) return true; else return false;` is exactly equivalent to `return validate == name;`.

Comment: But he wants to check the length of each name, not the length of the entire input.